# Заставить OpenVPN Server "работать через прокси"

Tags: windows, сервер, proxy, vpn, openvpn

На одной машине установлены клиент и сервер OpenVPN. Оба предназначены друг для друга. Требуется провернуть следующую цепочку:

`(vpnclient->vpnserver->socksproxy)->internet`

Всё, что в скобках находится на одной машине. Подключение клиента к серверу работает нормально.

Вопрос: что нужно дописать в конфиг сервера, чтобы он работал через прокси?

Основная проблема: ОС - Windows. На Linux давно бы уже iptables использовал.

Маны курил, в гугле был. Попробовал всё что нашёл - не работает "прокси".

Сервер:

```
dev tun
proto tcp
port 12345
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 120
verb 3
```

Клиент:

```
client
dev tunl
proto tcp
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
cipher AES-128-CBC
nobind
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
remote 127.0.0.1 12345
resolv-retry infinite
```

ОС Win10x64, OpenVPN 2.4

PS: виртуалка с линем под виндой, как промежуточный этап, не рассматривается. Всё должно быть на локальной тачке.

Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: В логике соединения должно быть так **(vpnclient->socksproxy -> vpnserver)->internet**. Иначе получается, что туннель установлен, а вот как клиенту, пользователю Интернета - будь то приложение, браузер и т.п., - следует догадаться о прокси в Вашем случае совершенно не понятно. Если только попытаться использовать сторонний софт соксификации: SocksChain, Proxycap, etc.

Comment: Хочу сделать аналог транспарентного прокси под винду. Чтобы весь траф шел через него. Для этого пробую юзать опенвпн. Поэтому интересует именно такая схема. Если такая схема не реализуема стандартными методами, то придётся либо патчить, либо хукать винсокс в процессе опенвпн